# Iterate over JSON using $.each to display images

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to display multiple gifs pulled through an API call after a search. I am able to get  the code to work when I only want to display one gif but I'm looking to iterate over the JSON file and display multiple gifs.

I'm trying to use $.each but whenever I do I get a combination of undefined related errors. I've tried all kinds of combinations of calling the data within the JSON array but still can't get it to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#gif-search-button').click(function (evt){
    
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    var url ='http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC'; 
    var gifRequest = 'q=' + $('#gif-search').val();
    gifCallback = function (data) {
      var returnedgif = '<div>';
       
        $.each(data, function(index, gif){
            
            
         returnedgif += '<a href="' + gif.data.url + '">';
         returnedgif += '<img id="resultGif" src="' + gif.data.images.fixed_height.url + '"></a>';
            console.log(returnedgif)
        })

          returnedgif += '</div>'
          
            $('#resultGif').html(returnedgif);
       
    } //End of callback function    
    
    $.getJSON(url, gifRequest, gifCallback);
        
    
}); //End of click event
    });
```

```html
 <div class="container">
            
            <form class='form-group search-form'>
               
                <div class="grid">
                
                    <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-sm-4" >
                        <label for="gif-search" class='lead'>What type of gif are you looking for?</label>
                        <input type="text" id="gif-search" class="form-control" placeholder='dancing bears' />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-danger search-form' id="gif-search-button">Find that gif</button>
                    </div>    

                </div>
                
            </form>
        
            
            <div id="resultGif">
       
            
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following in the iteration:

```
   $.each(data.data, function(index, gif){
```

The problem is that the response comes in the following structure

- data

  - gif1
  - ...
  - gifN

So in your code you should iterate over `data.data` as the first `data` is the variable returned from the `getJSON` provided as a parameter to the `gifCallback` and the second is what the API returns.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#gif-search-button').click(function (evt){
    
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    var url ='http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC'; 
    var gifRequest = 'q=' + $('#gif-search').val();
    gifCallback = function (data) {
      var returnedgif = '<div>';
       
        $.each(data.data, function(index, gif){
            
         returnedgif += '<a href="' + gif.url + '">';
         returnedgif += '<img id="resultGif" src="' + gif.images.fixed_height.url + '"></a>';
            console.log(returnedgif)
        })

          returnedgif += '</div>'
          
            $('#resultGif').html(returnedgif);
       
    } //End of callback function    
    
    $.getJSON(url, gifRequest, gifCallback);
        
    
}); //End of click event
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            
            <form class='form-group search-form'>
               
                <div class="grid">
                
                    <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-sm-4" >
                        <label for="gif-search" class='lead'>What type of gif are you looking for?</label>
                        <input type="text" id="gif-search" class="form-control" placeholder='dancing bears' />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-danger search-form' id="gif-search-button">Find that gif</button>
                    </div>    

                </div>
                
            </form>
        
            
            <div id="resultGif">
       
            
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
```